# Contact Form 7 — set the default value for select fields using the URL with right side of the pipe

Tags: wordpress, select, default-value, contact-form-7

I'm wondering how to set default value for select fields using the URL in Contact Form 7.

I know the following method :

```
[select* object default:get "A quote request|quote" "A request for information|information"]
```

And set default value with the following URL :
`mydomain.com/contact?object=A%20quote%20request`

But in this case, I want to set default value using the "right side of the pipe" to have better URL (without spaces, case sensitive or accented characters).

For instance : `mydomain.com/contact?object=quote` and display in the select the value "A quote request".

Thank you for your help !

Comment: The right side of the pipes aren't in the form, they're only passed to the email.

Comment: you can use a plugin extension like the [Smart Grid-layout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) that allows you to pre-fill forms with a hook, so you can dynamically fill the value at the time of the form page request.